# Google Voice SMS not showing notifications in Hangouts?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, google-voice, google-hangouts

I have my Google Voice account setup through the Hangouts app for Android, on my un-rooted Galaxy S5 (with the Lollipop OTA).

When I have the application open on my device, and I receive an SMS to my GV number, it appears on screen.

If I don't have the application open, the phone still receives the message, but it does not give me a notification. I know background data is turned on, and it has received the message, because I can turn on airplane mode, then open the app, and see the message is there unread.

*SMS* messages sent to my carrier number as well as *Actual* Hangouts messages notify correctly whether the app is open on-screen or not.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't disable the "Show notifications" option for Hangouts?  Settings -> Apps -> Hangouts, right under Force Stop.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. As I mentioned above, I still receive notifications for *Hangout* messages, as well as SMS messages, just not *Google Voice* SMS messages.

Comment: Just ruling out the low-hanging fruit first.  Next on that list - in Hangouts app, in Settings -> [your Google account], under "Google Voice - [your GV number]" section make sure a setting "Messages (Show SMS & voicemail in Hangouts)" is selected.

Comment: Yes, that setting is selected.

Comment: Do you have the actual [Google Voice app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice) installed?  I remember reading some article a while ago saying that it's still needed.

Comment: Then in the GV app's settings under "Sync and notifications", make sure the setting to receive text notifications is enabled.  It may be grayed out since your main SMS app is Hangouts, but it should still be checked.

Comment: Also, can you see if you are experiencing [this issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/hangouts/L83ljcYKfEs)? Basically every **new** conversation will have notifications disabled by default until you explicitly turn it on manually, and there is currently no way to override this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with Hangouts app that causes notifications for new conversations with a given contact to be disabled by default, with no way to override this setting.  On the Conversations tab, these are denoted by a bell with a strike-through:
[image]
[(click for larger image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co0Ku.jpg)

Once you open such a conversation you will see a message in red saying "Notifications off - You won't be notified of new messages" with an option to enable them:
[image]
[(click for larger image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktv19.png)

Existing conversations for which you've enabled this setting will receive notifications normally.  If you delete the conversation, the setting will revert to "off".  Archiving the conversation keeps it enabled.

The details that are described in [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!category-topic/hangouts/mobile-app/Pf9kAVOdouk) (I suggest starring it to show Google that there is interest in this issue) match exactly what you are experiencing.  It has been brought up [before](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/hangouts/L83ljcYKfEs), and was escalated to the Hangouts development team, who are [already aware](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/hangouts/asHJlYF355g/Ge3uE2p3JWIJ) of the issue.  We can only guess when (or if) Google will fix this.

Comment: Well, in my instance, this looks like it is absolutely the issue that I'm having. I was able to reproduce the exact behavior you've described. What a frustrating bug. Thanks for finding this.

Answer (score 4):

I found this post on a google product forum and it worked for me. After you follow the steps, if it helps, I used the following service to send a test text message to my phone knowing it wouldn't be in my contacts and IT WORKED :)

https://www.clickatell.com/test-sms-gateway/

Tokiyo said:
Found a solution trying to fix this problem. This will give you notifications of new messages from new numbers or new people on the Hangouts app.

1. Go to your Hangouts app
2. Menu
3. Settings
4. Your account email
5. Customize invites
6. Everyone Else
7. Select "Can contact you directly"

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2vjtje/try_this_fix_if_your_hangouts_app_doesnt_notify/